# Change tumblr share button css

Tags: html, css, tumblr

```
<div class="shareimg">
    <a class="tumblr-share-button" href="https://www.tumblr.com/share">
        <img src="../images/tumblr.png" /><br/>
        <span>Tumblr</span>
    </a>
    <script id="tumblr-js" async src="https://assets.tumblr.com/share-button.js"></script>  
</div>
```

i had created a tumblr button but whenever i run page, the whole div gets replaced by the tumblr's original share button. how can i stop this??

Comment: Did you copy the code from Tumblr itself?  If so, it has a script which may cause unexpected behavior.  If you want to have complete control over the button, use your own image and your own code.

Comment: Is that all you need to know?  If so, I'll post that as an answer.

Comment: I created my own image but it didn't worked. so , i used some other techniques.